# Initialialize Database on PhpList

Tags: mysql, phplist

I installed phplist in a test server hosted on my real machine and can not I initialize the database. I followed the following steps:

1. Copy the folder / lists in the main directory of the server.
2. Create the database from the command line MySQL.
3. Modify the access data to the database created.
4. Access the administration panel phplist http: // myservername / lists / admin
5. I get a message that has not been initialized database. I follow the link to do.
6. starts loading the page but nothing happens remains blank. If inspect the html code I can see that the  includes 'access denied'.

What can be the cause? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by putting below to config.php

```
define('CHECK_REFERRER',false);
```